# how can change the header address?

Tags: header, address

[image]

how can i change the address, where is the setting?
Also, the footer how can change the phone no and email?

Comment: Check From Magento Admin : Content -> Blocks, Widget and Pages, find the footer and then header block and then modify there

Answer (score 0):

Enable your debug mode from admin to check the Block path.

Enable Template Path Hints for Storefront :
`Store->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Enable Template Path Hints for Storefront` : **Yes** & rest of all set to **No**.

You can check path from front side.Just like below screenshot.

[image]